# Angular 4 routing - is it possible to have two router components

Tags: angular, routes, angular4-router

So, i'm using angular 4 to develop an app, and i have a problem. I want to use angular 4 routing to include two components in one page, but it doesn't seem to be doable in the way i want to do it. I have a component **header** which is just a navbar, and i have another component **home**, which already has a navbar so i don't want to include **header** with **home**, but with some other component **login** for example. So i tried looking at angular docs and the closest way to do this would be with childs, but i don't want **login** to be a child of **header**. I tried putting to **router-outlets** and two components in my **app.module.ts** file, but it didn't work out.

Comment: yes. It's possible, and easy :)

Comment: Use secondary aka auxiliary routes: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#secondary-routes

Comment: I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Comment: @DeborahK nice code examples, you should put that as an answer, I'd +1 it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main component could be displayed in the default router outlet and the second component could be displayed in a secondary, named router outlet like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then route to the secondary route like this:

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: { popup: ['messages']}}]);
```

You can see a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing